# Can't Log into Fedora 19 after force shutdown

Tags: fedora, kde, shutdown

I was exploring my new fedora 19 after a crash in KDE (I don't know what I just did). I couldn't shutdown my laptop either with the graphical method or the terminal way (because the terminal refused to open). So I forced the shutdown by pressing the shutdown button in my laptop. After I restarted my laptop and  entered my password and user, a black screen appeared and went back to logging screen again (the same thing happened with root).

So how should I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you access one of the ttys?  At the login prompt, try ctrl-alt-F2 and see if you can log in there.  If that's successful, something in X is probably corrupted.

Comment: Yes it was successful, and What do you mean by X ? . Now 90% i guess the Desktop environment is corrupted .

Comment: I'm not familiar with KDE, but you can check different log files to see if there are any errors: `/var/log/messages` or `~/.xsession-errors` (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to enter recovery mode and reset the root users password (which may have ended up corrupted).  Fedora has an answer on that:

[How to reset a root password](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_reset_a_root_password)

Comment: I don't think the problem about the passwords, Cause when i enter wrong password, he refuse to log in, but i make the right password the black screen appear.